# AJAX success callback function not called

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

i'm working with python and js on a simple website.
i'm trying to call a method from the client side and get result, but no matter what i do 
success function isnt happening.

this is my JS

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/gtest/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { information : "You have a very nice website, sir."},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert ("post is success");
        },
        error: function(request,error) { 
            alert(request.responseText);
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

this is my server side code

```
def gtest(request):
    jsonValidateReturn = simplejson.dumps({"jsonValidateReturn": "ddddd"})
    return HttpResponse(jsonValidateReturn, content_type='application/json', mimetype='application/json')
```

The server responds to the call - 
"POST /api/gtest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31

tried to go over similar questions here but with no success :\
no matter what I do, only the error function is called.
the error alert is always empty.. no actual message.

I know this is probably a small change but I can't find it.

Comment: Where is the `.ajax()` call being triggered from?

Comment: Don't you think it would help if we knew what things are being alerted in the `error` callback? Usually, when you get a `200` status back but it goes to `error`, that means there was a problem with the parsing/returned data.

Comment: do you know if gtest is being run?

Comment: the .ajax() is call from a simple "onclick" function..
the error is always empty.. i know message
gtest is run becuase i printed to the console and it printed..

Comment: Could there be a cross-domain issue? There would be if you're running the JS from `localhost` and sending the request to `127.0.0.1`. What is your response code in `request.status`? If it is `0`, that indicates a cross-domain error; if it is `200` then it's not.

Comment: Is there anything in your JavaScript console?

Comment: You don't seem to call any specific page ? Could it be the problem ?

Comment: apsillers - the status is 0. i changed the url in the .ajax to: "http://localhost:8000/api/gtest/" and status is still 0.

in the JavaScript console i get : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/gtest/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: CORS error. Read up [on it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin). Either add a proxy to your PHP, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your server to allow cross domain requests, or switch to JSONP....

Comment: You are running the script on a `file:` page, yes? If you had mentioned that error in the first place (or done a [Google search for it](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1Y3NDUG_enUS503US503&aq=f&client=tablet-android-asus-nexus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&q=Origin+null+is+not+allowed+by+Access-Control-Allow-Origin)) you'd have you solution almost immediately. Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant upvote  mccannf's comment.

The problem was solved by the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) he posted, i ran the html code from a file on my pc and i needed to load it from the server so link wont start with file:// but with http://

best regards..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/gtest/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
         'information' : "You have a very nice website, sir.",
         'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
    },
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert ("post is success");
    },
    error: function(request,error) { 
        alert(request.responseText);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Explain the csrfmiddlewaretoken

Comment: I also experienced your problem, I cannot get the success. I do not know why but when I check my data it's saving but the output not goes on success.